# What is limitation in support of Polymer.import?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I am using something like this:

```
Polymer.import('file.html');
```

It works as expected but also outputs:

```
Dynamically loading html imports has very limited support right now in dart, see http://dartbug.com/17873.
```

I have tried to dart2js and it works good even in Internet Explorer. Can someone explain me what is the limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it doesn't support to execute Dart code referenced or included in the imported HTML.

Comment: In html file: `<paper-button on-tap="{{test}}">Test</paper-button>` and `<script type="application/dart" src="test.dart"></script>` in test.dart `void test() { print("TEST");}` and it works

Comment: I am sorry, you are right, I forgot to remove `<link rel="import"...`